# Electromagnetic induction in an open loop?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

So I was solving a problem where there was a parabolic conductor lying in a region of uniform magnetic field (B) and a conducting rod was sliding on it, and its acceleration was given by 'w'.But how can an emf be induced in parabola despite of the fact that it is not a closed loop?

Comment: i think the moving conductor  makes the parabolic open curve close.

Comment: why you added Quantum electrodynamics as tag? Be careful and don't write arbitrarily

Comment: Yes it was my fault . I should have tagged it under electromagnetism or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Movement of Conducting rod on the parabolic conductor make a closed loop.

and since the conducting rod is accelerating, the area of the loop becomes time dependent and hence the flux.
so the EMF will be induced due to dime dependent change of flux.

Answer (score 0):

The moving conductor is making the loop closed. As it slides down, the flux through the loop slowly decreases and this leads to the formation of an emf